# Egg and basket in pygame; struggling with collision detection between egg and basket

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. This is one of the few cases where the code just does not respond and doesn't give a traceback, carrying on as if its "normal". My goal here is to create a simple game that has the player move a basket back and forth. I've coded it in a particularly odd way, but I felt like even though the method is dirty, it gets the job done. I guess it's coming back to haunt me. *I've consulted my teacher, IRC, and friends. None of them have given me a straight answer or just admit to not knowing what the problem really is, or give me the generic answer of looking at documentation.*

```
#The egg and basket game

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import random
x=260
y=541
score = 0
lives = 3

#Screen initialize
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("egg")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Basket
basket=pygame.image.load("art/basket.png")
basket_rect = basket.get_rect()

#egg
egg=pygame.image.load("art/egg.png")
egg_rect = egg.get_rect()

def eggy(xegg, yegg):
    screen.blit(egg,(xegg, yegg))

def basketey(x, y):
    screen.blit(basket,(x, y))

#Movement of basket
ychange=0
xchange=0
exiting=False


xegg = random.randrange(50,550)
yegg = 20
while not exiting:
    if yegg<550:
        yegg += 2
        eggy(xegg, yegg)

    elif egg_rect.colliderect(basket_rect):
        yegg=20
        xegg = random.randrange(50,550)
        yegg=yegg+ychange

        score += 1

        eggy(xegg, yegg)

    else:
        yegg=20
        xegg = random.randrange(50,550)
        yegg=yegg+ychange

        lives -= 1

        eggy(xegg, yegg)

    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            exiting=True
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                xchange=-5
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xchange=5
        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT or event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xchange=0

    x=x+xchange

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    basketey(x, y)
    eggy(xegg, yegg)

    if x > 600 - 78 or x < 0:
        xchange = 0

    if lives == 0:
        print("Game Over, Your score was: %s" % score)
        exiting = True

    pygame.display.update()

ychange=0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Please describe what happens when it doesn't work? Also you never change `ychange` if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main issue is that your are calling:

```
egg_rect.colliderect(basket_rect)
```

This is correct, but you never update the rectangles. Each rectangle has an x, y, width, and height property. All you update is the variable yegg. If you replace all the instances of yegg with egg_rect.y, then you are now updating the rectangle of the egg so the collision will work.

The same goes for the basket. Be sure you are updating the x, y coordinates of the rectangle, because that is what you need for the collision.

For example:

```
if egg_rect.y < 550:
    egg_rect.y += 2
else:
    egg_rect.y = 20
    egg_rect.x = random.randrange(50, 550)
    lives -= 1

if egg_rect.colliderect(basket_rect):
    egg_rect.y=20
    egg_rect.x = random.randrange(50,550)
    score += 1
```

I will leave the rest to you.